# Recommended CPU upgrade for Dell Vostro 220 with Intel E7300 processor?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, intel-core2, lga775, dell-vostro

I've got a Dell Vostro 220 with an E7300 processor (Intel Core 2 Duo @ 2.66Mhz, LGA775 socket) and I'm thinking about upgrading my processor so I can run Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V, which requires Hardware Virtualization support in the processor.

Yes, I know this is underpowered for a server, I'm actually using it as a desktop machine but I'd like to use Hyper-V instead of Virtual Server (which I'm using now for running VMs).

I'd like to keep the same motherboard and ideally the same CPU fan and RAM too.

Any suggestions for a good, relatively cheap (under $200) processor upgrade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching around, it appears that the highest chip supported by Dell is an E8600. There are probably unsupported options as well, but YMMV.

Comment: Does "Supported by Dell" mean that my chipset (G43/G45 Express) and my RAM (PC2 6400) are compatible too? Also, how about heat-- am I likely to have to buy a new CPU cooler?

Comment: You should be OK in those fronts since Dell sells that chip as an option in the Vostro 220s. "Supported by Dell" means, what they officially sell and support. Some people have gotten other CPUs to work, but stability and functionality are not guaranteed, since they don't put out BIOS updates and the like with those CPUs in mind.